# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part II

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/378402).)

**Note that $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ if and only if $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.  I have therefore undeleted this question, in view of this closely related MSE question: [When does $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))$ equal $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$? What are the exceptions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3628078).**

In what follows, we let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.  We also let $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From this [paper in NNTDM](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/), we have the equation
$$i(q) := \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right).$$

In particular, we know that the *index* $i(q)$ is an integer greater than $5$ by a result of [Dris and Luca](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1437).

> **We now attempt to compute an expression for $\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right)$ in terms of $i(q)$.**

First, since we have
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma({q^k}{n^2}) = \sigma(N) = 2N = 2{q^k}{n^2}$$
we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(n^2)} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{i(q)}$$
and
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = {q^k}\cdot\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg) = {q^k}{i(q)},$$
so that we get
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg).$$

Now, since $\gcd(q, n) = \gcd(q^k, 2n^2) =  1$ and $i(q)$ is odd, we get
$$\gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

**The following is copied verbatim from this [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357521/10365) to a closely related question:**

> Here is a conditional proof that
> $$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

As derived in the OP, we have
$$G = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

This is equivalent to
$$G = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\gcd\bigg(n^2, (i(q))^2\bigg) = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\bigg(\gcd(n, i(q))\bigg)^2.$$

But we also have
$$\gcd(n, i(q)) = \gcd\bigg(n, \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(n^2), \gcd(n, n^2)\bigg) = \gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)).$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$G = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\bigg(\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2 = \frac{\bigg(\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))}.$$

In particular, we get
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
**if and only if** $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$.

**We now try to express $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ as a linear combination of $n^2$ and $\sigma(n^2)$:**

To begin with, write
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \frac{(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))(q - 1)}{q^k - 1}.$$

Now, using the identity
$$\frac{A}{B}=\frac{C}{D}=\frac{A-C}{B-D},$$
where $B \neq 0$, $D \neq 0$, and $B \neq D$, we obtain
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2) - (2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))(q - 1)}{q^k - (q^k - 1)}$$
from which we get
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \sigma(n^2) - (2n^2 - \sigma(n^2))(q - 1) = 2n^2 - q(2n^2 - \sigma(n^2)) = 2n^2 - qD(n^2),$$
or equivalently,
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = 2(1 - q)n^2 + q\sigma(n^2).$$

> *Note that the linear combination for $\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ was obtained without assuming the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture for odd perfect numbers that $k=1$.*

**Here is my question:**

> How can I then derive a linear combination for $\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2))$ in terms of $\sigma(q^k)$ and $\sigma(n^2)$?  Note that this should always be (*unconditionally*) possible by [Bezout's Identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezoutsIdentity.html).

Comment: why is $\gcd\bigg(\sigma(n^2), \gcd(n, n^2)\bigg) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$ and not $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))$ as $\gcd(n, n^2)=n$ not $n^2$?

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Conrad!  I have addressed your concern in this [separate MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3628078).