# If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $k \neq 1$ (MSE version)

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, conjectures, divisor-sum, open-problem

**Note that $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ if and only if $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$.  I have therefore undeleted this question, in view of this closely related MSE question: [When does $\gcd(m,\sigma(m^2))$ equal $\gcd(m^2,\sigma(m^2))$? What are the exceptions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3628078).**

(Cross-posting this question from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357535), as I think it is about to be closed there, due to some reasons yet unknown to myself.)

This question is directly related to this [earlier one ("On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part II")](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626486) in MSE.

*That question has all the details.*

Now, let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently Sorli conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.

In the hyperlinked MSE question, we have the equation
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
where
$$i(q)=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}.$$

Assume to the contrary that $k=1$.  By [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01591.pdf), it follows that $q < n$, whence it follows that $\sigma(q^k) = \sigma(q) = q + 1 < n$.

But $i(q) = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$; in particular, this means that
$$i(q) \mid \sigma(q^k) \implies \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \leq \sigma(q^k).$$
We know that $\sigma(q^k) < n$, so we have
$$2n < \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \leq \sigma(q^k) < n,$$
resulting in a contradiction.

We therefore conclude that $k \neq 1$.

Comment: Also, unconditionally I get
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \leq \sigma(q^k)$$
which implies that
$$\frac{8n^2}{5} < \sigma(n^2) \leq q^k \sigma(q^k) < \frac{5q^{2k}}{4},$$
from which we obtain
$$n^2 < \frac{32n^2}{25} < q^{2k},$$
which finally implies that $n < q^k$.

Comment: the computations in the linked question are not correct as they use the incorrect fact that $gcd(n,n^2)=n^2$ when in fact $gcd(n,n^2)=n$ on the line where you deduce that $gcd(i(q),n)=i(q)$

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Conrad.  I have addressed your concern in a separate MSE question (as indicated at the start of the edited OP).