# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part III

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This post is an offshoot of this earlier [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3626486/28816).)

In what follows, we let $\sigma(x)$ denote the sum of divisors of the positive integer $x$.  We also let $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ denote the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From this [paper in NNTDM](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-2/12-20/), we have the equation
$$i(q) := \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})}=\gcd\left(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\right). \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

In particular, we know that the *index* $i(q)$ is an integer greater than $5$ by a result of [Dris and Luca](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1437).

> **We now attempt to compute an expression for $\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right)$ in terms of $i(q)$.**

First, since we have
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma({q^k}{n^2}) = \sigma(N) = 2N = 2{q^k}{n^2}$$
we obtain
$$\sigma(q^k) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(n^2)} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{i(q)}$$
and
$$\sigma(n^2) = \frac{2 q^k n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = {q^k}\cdot\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}\bigg) = {q^k}{i(q)},$$
so that we get
$$\gcd\left(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\right) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg).$$

Now, since $\gcd(q, n) = \gcd(q^k, 2n^2) =  1$ and $i(q)$ is odd, we get
$$\gcd\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{i(q)}, {q^k}{i(q)}\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

**The following is copied verbatim from this [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357521/10365) to a closely related question:**

> Here is a conditional proof that
> $$G = \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

As derived in the OP, we have
$$G = \gcd\bigg(\frac{n^2}{i(q)}, i(q)\bigg).$$

This is equivalent to
$$G = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\gcd\bigg(n^2, (i(q))^2\bigg) = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\bigg(\gcd(n, i(q))\bigg)^2.$$

But we also have
$$\gcd(n, i(q)) = \gcd\bigg(n, \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))\bigg) = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(n^2), \gcd(n, n^2)\bigg) = \gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)).$$

Consequently, we obtain
$$G = \frac{1}{i(q)}\cdot\bigg(\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2 = \frac{\bigg(\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))}.$$

In particular, we get
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
**if and only if** $\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$.

*Here is an attempt at proving the following conjecture:*

> **CONJECTURE:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then the inequation
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2)) \neq \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
> holds.

**MY ATTEMPT AT A PROOF**

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.

Assume to the contrary that $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k), \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

By the considerations above, we obtain
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)).$$

But note that we also have
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)).$$

This implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)),$$
from which we get the divisibility constraint
$$\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \mid n$$
which gives
$$\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \mid 1$$
and then
$$n = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

We obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = i(q) = n = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

It follows that
$$\sigma(n^2) = q^k n = \frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

In particular, note that we obtain the following equations from equation $\eqref{eq1}$, after multiplying through by $(q^k \sigma(q^k))/2$:
$$\frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = \frac{q^k \sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\gcd(n, \sigma(n^2)) = q^k n^2 = N = n\sigma(n^2).$$

> *Alas, this is where I get stuck.  I was hoping somebody out there might have some bright ideas on how to prove either $k=1$ or $q^k < n$ (in order to arrive at a contradiction), under the assumption that
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),$$
> where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?*

**POSTSCRIPT:** Note that to prove $k=1$, it [suffices to show](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) that
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} \mid n^2.$$
Compare with what we have:
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = n \mid n^2.$$

**UPDATE (October 30, 2020 - 1:53 PM Manila time)** I have just posted what appears to be a complete proof of the conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**solution-verification**

> $$\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \mid n$$
> which gives
> $$\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \mid 1$$
> and then
> $$n = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

Writing $\dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \mid 1$, you are implicitly using that $\dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$ is an integer, but I don't see why $\dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$ is an integer.

---

After assuming that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
we have
$$i(q)= \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \frac{D(n^2)}{\sigma(q^{k-1})} = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$$
So, we can have
$$0\lt\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{n}\le\frac nn=1$$
from which we can at least say that
$$\text{$\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$ is an integer}\iff \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=n\iff n=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove.  Since
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \gcd(n, \sigma(n^2))$$
follows from
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)),$$
then we have
$$\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} \mid n,$$
from which we get
$$n = a\cdot\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)},$$
which implies that
$$1 = a\cdot\frac{2n}{\sigma(q^k)},$$
for some positive integer $a$.  Does it not follow that
$$1 = a = \frac{2n}{\sigma(q^k)},$$
since $1 = 1\cdot{1}$, trivially?

Comment: Ahh, now I see your point, @mathlove!  Looking at your answer again, I was indeed implicitly assuming that $$\frac{2n}{\sigma(q^k)}$$ is an integer.  =(