# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part VII

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Pardon me for being somewhat stubborn, but this question will be the last for this week.  This post is an offshoot of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372061).)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Set
$$G := \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$H := \gcd\bigg(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$I := \gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg).$$

It is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690494) (and fairly easy to prove) that
$$GH = I^2.$$

It is [also known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4372075/28816) (and also very easy to prove) that the divisibility chain
$$G \mid I \mid H$$
holds.

Here is my:

> **INITIAL QUESTION:** What is the value of
> $$\frac{I}{G}=\frac{H}{I}?$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I claim that
$$\dfrac{I}{G} = \dfrac{H}{I} = \dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
if and only if $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.

To this end, initially it must be the case that
$$\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n \iff n \mid \sigma(n^2),$$
basically because of the equation
$$\frac{q^k n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n}.$$
But we also have
$$n \mid \sigma(n^2) \iff G = \sigma(q^k)/2$$
from **Theorem B** in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259745).
Since $H$ is also the **index of $N$ at the prime $q$**, then
$$H = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$
Also, we obtain
$$n \mid \sigma(n^2) \iff I = n.$$
We therefore obtain
$$\dfrac{I}{G} = \dfrac{H}{I} = \dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
which is an integer, if and only if $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.

> **FINAL QUESTION:** What is the value of
> $$\frac{I}{G}=\frac{H}{I}$$
> if $\sigma(q^k)/2$ **does not divide** $n$?

Comment: FYI, one can at least say that $\dfrac HI=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)\sigma(q^k)/2}$$=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n\sigma(q^k)/2,\sigma(n^2)\sigma(q^k)/2\bigg)}$$=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n\sigma(q^k)/2,n^2q^k\bigg)}$$=\dfrac{n}{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,nq^k\bigg)}$$=\dfrac{n}{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\bigg)}$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Please flesh out your last comment as an actual answer, so that I can upvote.  =)

Comment: I noticed that, since
$$H = \dfrac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
then we obtain
$$\gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg) = I = \dfrac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \cdot \gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(q^k)/2\bigg).$$

Comment: Additionally, we also obtain
$$\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\bigg) = G = \dfrac{\Bigg(\gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(q^k)/2\bigg)\Bigg)^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

FYI, one can at least say that
$$\begin{align}\dfrac HI&=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)\sigma(q^k)/2}=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n\sigma(q^k)/2,\sigma(n^2)\sigma(q^k)/2\bigg)}
\\\\&=\dfrac{n^2}{\gcd\bigg(n\sigma(q^k)/2,n^2q^k\bigg)}=\dfrac{n}{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,nq^k\bigg)}
\\\\&=\dfrac{n}{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\bigg)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, @mathlove!  I did not expect this.  =)