# Does $I = \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) = (\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2})\cdot\gcd(\sigma(q^k)/2,n)$ imply that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ holds?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the GCDs:
$$G = \gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$H = \gcd\bigg(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg)$$
$$I = \gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg).$$

In this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116), Dris shows that the identity
$$G \times H = I^2$$
holds.

The proof of the divisibility constraint $I \mid H$ trivially follows from the GCD property
$$\bigg(a \mid b\bigg) \implies \bigg(\gcd(a,c) \mid \gcd(b,c)\bigg).$$

It then follows that
$$J = \frac{I}{G} = \frac{H}{I} = \sqrt{\frac{H}{G}}$$
must be an (odd) integer.

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372679), the anonymous MSE user [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/78967) shows that the value of $J$ may be given as
$$J = \frac{n}{\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\bigg)}.$$

Thus, we get
$$I = \gcd\bigg(n,\sigma(n^2)\bigg) = \bigg(\frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}\bigg)\cdot\gcd\bigg(\sigma(q^k)/2,n\bigg), \tag{*}$$
since it is known that
$$H = \gcd\bigg(n^2,\sigma(n^2)\bigg) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Can you show that Equation **(*)** unconditionally implies $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ (since $I$ must be an integer)?

Comment: Since $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2$ holds in general, then $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ is true if $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **squarefree**.

Comment: Furthermore, note that the divisibility constraint $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ implies the divisibility condition $G \mid I$, which is **true**.

Comment: Lastly, note that
$$\frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)} = \frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2},$$
so that the divisibility condition $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid \sigma(n^2)$ implies that the divisibility constraint $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ holds.

Comment: What is the evidence that $\frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)} = \frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$, holds?

Comment: Isn't there a possibility that this equation could also hold? $\frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)} = \frac{gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) }{n}$

Comment: @Mathguru: Thank you for your time and attention.  In fact,
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$$
holds, so that both
$$\frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)} = \frac{n}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$$
and
$$\frac{\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))}{\gcd(n,\sigma(q^k)/2)} = \frac{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}{n}$$
hold.  For more details, you are hereby referred to this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08116).