# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part IV

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

This question is related to this [post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626486) and this [post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690494).  Hereinafter, we will let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$, and $\gcd(y,z)$ will denote the *greatest common divisor* of the (positive) integers $y$ and $z$.

Let $m=q^k n^2$ be an *odd perfect number* with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From the hyperlinked posts, we have
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{\sigma(n^2)/q^k}=\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{2n^2/\sigma(q^k)}=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{n^2}}.$$

Since the **LHS** is an integer, the **RHS** is also an integer.  But $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is an integer.  Therefore,
$$\frac{\bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\bigg)^2}{n^2} = \frac{\gcd\bigg(n^2,(\sigma(n^2))^2\bigg)}{n^2} = \gcd\Bigg(1, \bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n}\bigg)^2\Bigg)$$
is an integer, which is just equal to $1$, and this further means that $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.

Hence, we have the following proposition:

> **THEOREM A:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

In particular, this **Theorem** implies the following **Corollary**:

> **COROLLARY:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) \geq 3.$$

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Is this argument logically sound?  If it is not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

**EDIT: (September 26, 2021 - 2:16 PM Manila time)** From the comments, I realized that what I actually have is the following modification to **THEOREM A** (*note the additional divisibility condition on $\sigma(n^2)$*):

> **THEOREM B:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, satisfying $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, then
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

Comment: I don't see why you can say that $\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$ is an integer from $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot{\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}}$. Something like $75=\dfrac{54}{2}\cdot\dfrac{5^2}{3^2}$ might happen where $\dfrac{5^2}{3^2}$ is not an integer. I think that to prove that $\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$ is an integer, you have to prove that $\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$ divides $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$.

Comment: That is exactly my point, @mathlove!  We do have
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \mid \sigma(q^k) \mid \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)).$$
(The first divisibility constraint makes use of $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, so that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is an integer, and at the same time, $A/2 \mid A$, where $A=\sigma(q^k)$.  The second divisibility constraint just makes use of the definition of GCD, so that $A$ divides $\gcd(A, B)$, where $B=\sigma(n^2)$.)

Comment: $A$ does not always divide $\gcd(A,B)$. For example, take $A=7,B=2$ for which $\gcd(A,B)=1$ holds.

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake while scouring the web for the appropriate GCD property to back my claim, for which I found none, @mathlove.  If you could write out your last two comments as an actual answer, then I will upvote and then accept.  Thanks!  =)

Comment: Do you have a proof for your assertion that "to prove that $\frac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$ is an integer, then one has to prove that $\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$ divides $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$"?  Can you please add that proof to your answer below, @mathlove?  Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: You have $\dfrac{A}{B}=C$ where $A=\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)),B=\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$ and $C=\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$. So, $C$ is an integer $\iff\dfrac AB$ is an integer $\iff B\mid A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Now, I understand.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you can say that $\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$ is an integer from $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\frac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}.$$ Something like $75=\dfrac{54}{2}\cdot\dfrac{5^2}{3^2}$ might happen where $\dfrac{5^2}{3^2}$ is not an integer. I think that to prove that $\dfrac{(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)))^2}{n^2}$ is an integer, you have to prove that $\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}2$ divides $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$.

---

It is true that $\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\mid \sigma(q^k)$, but I don't see why you can say that
$$\sigma(q^k)\mid \gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))$$

---

$A$ does not always divide $\gcd(A,B)$. For example, take $A=7,B=2$ for which $\gcd(A,B)=1$ holds.