# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part V

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(**Note:** This post is *tangentially related* to this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259745).)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with *special/Eulerian prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is known that
$$i(q):=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}$$
and this follows easily from the fact that $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$.

**Recall that GCD is associative:**
$$\gcd(A,\gcd(B,C))=\gcd(\gcd(A,B),C)$$
for positive integers $A, B, C$, and **that GCD is commutative:**
$$\gcd(D,E)=\gcd(E,D)$$
for positive integers $D, E$.

With these initial considerations out of the way, let us prove the following propositions:

> **Proposition 1:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $$\gcd(n^4,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

**Proof:** Since $\gcd(q,n)=1$ and $q$ is prime, then
$$1=\gcd(q^k,n^2)=\gcd\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{i(q)},n^2\Bigg)=\frac{\gcd\Bigg(\sigma(n^2),n^2 {i(q)}\Bigg)}{i(q)}=\frac{\gcd\Bigg(\sigma(n^2),{n^2}\cdot{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))}\Bigg)}{i(q)}.$$
It follows that by GCD Commutativity that
$$1=\frac{\gcd\Bigg(\sigma(n^2),\gcd(n^2{\sigma(n^2)},n^4)\Bigg)}{i(q)}$$
and then, by GCD Associativity, that
$$1=\frac{\gcd\Bigg(\gcd(\sigma(n^2),n^2{\sigma(n^2)}),n^4\Bigg)}{i(q)}.$$
Since $\sigma(n^2) \mid {n^2 \sigma(n^2)}$, then we obtain
$$1=\frac{\gcd(\sigma(n^2),n^4)}{i(q)}$$
from which we get
$$1=\frac{\gcd(n^4,\sigma(n^2))}{i(q)}$$
by GCD Commutativity.

Hence, we finally have
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=i(q)=\gcd(n^4,\sigma(n^2)),$$
which is what we set out to prove for in **Proposition 1**.

**QED.**

Similarly, by considering $\gcd(q^k,n)=1$ as a starting point and following exactly the same line of reasoning as in the proof of **Proposition 1**, we obtain the following proposition:

> **Proposition 2:** If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then
> $$\gcd(n^3,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

**Proof:** (The proof is left as an exercise for the interested reader.)

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** *Could it then be proved that*
> $$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))?$$
> *If a(n) (alternative) proof for this last equation is not possible, could you explain why?*

Comment: FYI, you idea suggests that if $a$ is such that $1=\gcd(q^k,n^a)$, then $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^{a+2},\sigma(n^2))$ holds. Since $a$ cannot be $-1$, I think that another idea is needed to deal with $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  If you could please write out your last comment as an actual answer, then I will be more than obliged to upvote it.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

FYI, you idea suggests that if $a$ is such that $1=\gcd(q^k,n^a)$, then $$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^{a+2},\sigma(n^2))$$ holds.

Since $a$ cannot be $−1$, I think that another idea is needed to deal with $\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))$.