# On odd perfect numbers and a GCD - Part VI

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(**Note:** This post is closely related to [this earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341573).)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with *special/Eulerian prime* $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Suppose that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is **squarefree**.  Then since the condition "$\sigma(q^k)/2$ divides $n^2$" holds in general, we know that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ divides $n$.

The condition "$\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree" <s>is equivalent to</s> *implies* the condition "$n$ divides $\sigma(n^2)$".  (See this MO question and the [answer contained therein](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404913/10365) for the details.)

But the condition "$n$ divides $\sigma(n^2)$" implies that $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\sigma(q^k)/2$.

(Again, see the details in the MO question above.)

Furthermore, it is known that, if $n$ divides $\sigma(n^2)$, then we have
$$\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))=n.$$
In general, we know that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$$
holds.

Note that, since it is known that
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\frac{\Bigg(\gcd(n,\sigma(n^2))\Bigg)^2}{\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))},$$ then if $n$ divides $\sigma(n^2)$, we have
$$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) \iff \gcd(n,\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
$$\iff n = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2} \iff \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} = n.$$

But this contradicts $\sigma(q^k)/2$ being squarefree and (Steuerwald, 1937) who showed that $n$ must contain a square factor.  (See this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/226466/10365) for more information.)

The contradiction thus obtained implies that we have the following theorem:

> **THEOREM:**  Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Suppose that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree.  It follows that
> $$\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2)) \neq \gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)).$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Is this proof correct?

---

**REFERENCE**

```
    R. Steuerwald, "Verschärfung einer notwendigen Bedingung für die Existenz einer
    ungeraden vollkommenen Zahl," S.-B. Math.-Nat. Abt. Bayer. Akad. Wiss., 1937, pp. 68-73.
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think that it is false that if $\sigma(q^k)/2$ divides $n$, then $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree. Take $q=17,k=1$ and $n=9t$ where $t$ is an odd integer such that $\gcd(17,t)=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  If $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$, then since $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2$ holds in general, it follows that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree.  (I got this fact from [this tangentially related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1848171) and [the answer contained therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848177/28816).)  If you recall, it was you who referred me to this question via an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192325/28816) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4192266).

Comment: [The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848177/78967) says that if $n$ is squarefree and $n\mid a^2$ then every prime of $n$ divides $a$ and therefore, $n$ divides $a$. It does not say that if $n\mid a^2$ and $n\mid a$, then $n$ is squarefree.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it mixed up.  So I think I should *suppose that* $\sigma(q^k)/2$ **is squarefree**, to begin with.  Then since the condition $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2$ holds in general, it follows that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$.  This then implies that $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$.  Do you concur, @mathlove?

Comment: Additionally, per your last comment @mathlove, the condition $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n$ implies $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, but these two conditions are no longer equivalent.

Comment: I am updating the question in a while to reflect these recent edits.  Thanks, @mathlove!

Comment: If you could write out an answer confirming the correctness of the above proof, I will be more than obliged to upvote then accept it, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: I meant to say: "Additionally, per your last comment @mathlove, the condition $\sigma(q^k)/2$ **is squarefree** implies $n \mid \sigma(n^2)$, but these two conditions are no longer equivalent."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found any errors in your proof, so I think that your proof is correct.

---

I think that your proof can be simplified a bit as follows :

Suppose that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is squarefree.

Then, we know that $\sigma(q^k)/2\mid n,n\mid \sigma(n^2)$ and $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\sigma(q^k)/2$ hold.

In general, we know that $\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))=\dfrac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}$ holds.

So, we have
$$\begin{align}\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))&\iff \sigma(q^k)/2=\frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}
\\\\&\iff n^2=\bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\bigg)^2
\\\\&\iff n=\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\end{align}$$
So, supposing that $\gcd(\sigma(q^k),\sigma(n^2))=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ implies that $n$ is squarefree, which contradicts that $n$ is not squarefree.

Comment: Thank you very much for this confirmatory answer, @mathlove!  =)